# drop or delete a sqlite - table as fast as possible on Android device

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have a table with 1400 rows. Every row has a blob field which holds data between 10kb and 500kb. I need to delete that table. It takes me 3.5 minutes to delete the table and 3 minutes to drop the table. Thats too long for the users. 
How can I remove that table as fast as possible ? ( No rollback needed or any security, just remove it. )

I already tried the following.
1. Set pagesize :

```
sqlitedatabase.setPageSize(8000);
sqlitedatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + sTableName);
```

2. deactivate journallog which did not work.

```
sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF",null);
sqlitedatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + sTableName);
```

this doesn't work for me. journal log, which I guess takes a lot of time, is still be written on to the disk.

Comment: If you put this table in a separate database you can just delete the database file and recreate the database. That should be quicker than 3 minutes. But how is it taking so long to just drop a table?

Comment: Because my database has other filled tables which should not be deleted. I still have to delete the table in my original db.

Comment: What I was saying is, do you need this table to be in the same database as your other data? If not, what I said works. Or, as rutter says, you can use attach and detach.

Comment: Thanks you. But I need all tables within one db. I would also like to join the tables. I know this would be also possible with attach. But I guess this is not very performant and I do not want to split my data into several databases . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

From the [SQLite manual](http://sqlite.org/speed.html) (with emphasis added):

> **SQLite is slower than the other databases when it comes to dropping tables.** This probably is because when SQLite drops a table, it has to go through and erase the records in the database file that deal with that table. MySQL and PostgreSQL, on the other hand, use separate files to represent each table so they can drop a table simply by deleting a file, which is much faster.

You do have the option of creating and storing multiple database files, which you can then manage from a single connection with [`ATTACH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) and [`DETACH`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) queries.

Here's an example I just ran in SQLite3's command-line client:

```
sqlite> ATTACH 'example.sqlite' AS example;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE example.ex ( a INTEGER );
sqlite> INSERT INTO example.ex VALUES (1),(2),(3);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM example.ex;
1
2
3
sqlite> DETACH example;
sqlite>
```

Since the `ex` table is in its own file, `example.sqlite`, I can simply detach that DB from the connection and delete the entire file, which will be much faster.

Bear in mind that the number of DBs you can attach is fairly low (with [default compile options](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_limit_attached.html#sqlitelimitattached): 7). I've also read that foreign keys aren't supported in this scenario, though that info might be out of date.

Comment: I don't think that is good for my situation. In my DB are several tables ( more then 7 ), which should also be joinable. I would like to have all my tables in one db.  But I think about this.

Comment: You mean, you want to have your cake and eat it.

Comment: yes of course. I found a solution. ( enableWriteAheadLogging )

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution for me, which speeds up the deletion 6 times. 
with

```
connection_read.enableWriteAheadLogging();
```

I drop my table in 30 Seconds. Without it it takes the mentoined 3 minutes.
enableWriteAheadLogging is an alternative journal log which is way faster.

Comment: Had a similar problem with slow deletes. This helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the drop table code in a separate thread? The user shouldn't have to wait for the app to drop a table.

Comment: The User has to wait in my case. I delete the entire table and then I insert the new records. After the table is filled, it shows the data to the user. So the user has to wait and I am interrested in doing this very fast.

Comment: The Idea is good. When renaming the table and recreate/refill the original table, I could drop the cloned table in a separate thread. I tested this, but during the thread is running the gui stocks/slows down.